# Allowing machines other than localhost access to CUPS?

Tags: linux, printing, cups

In relation to [this question on printing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/how-to-print-from-ipad-to-cups), I have found that I cannot administer the CUPS instance from a different machine.  Is it possible that CUPS is configured to accept jobs only from the local machine, also?  Is there a way to configure CUPS to accept jobs from other machines on the network?  What is it?

A test of setting up another machine to print raw to the server in question (using the lpd protocol, lpd://server/printqueue) does not seem to be working either.  The server is Ubuntu 10.10.

I see the following entry in the cupsd.conf file which suggests that CUPS may only accept jobs locally:

```
# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen localhost:631
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about that line. Change it to `Listen 0.0.0.0:631` in order to have it listen on all IPv4-enabled interfaces.

Comment: This works for printing but not for web interface, which on remote access reports an "access denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to change interface on which CUPS is listening (as described above) you need to enable remote administration in CUPS web panel (in Administration tab)

[image]